# Retrofit returns a BAD Request 400 when I send a Json but in Postman it works

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

Retrofit returns a bad request 400 when I send a data class by @body with @Post method using retrofit2 v2.9.0 and GsonConverterFactory, but if I send a string the server does accept the request and returns 200 OK, only the GsonConverterFactory I alter the structure of the JSon by adding slash "/"

I want to send a Post request with Body, the api expects a json with the following structure:

Structure that the server expects

```
{
   "query": [
     {
       "IdGuia": "1ZY49W410406606690"
     }
   ]
}
```

When I send the request, the server returns a bad 400, but in postman it works fine.

This is my service class where I get the data that I want to send by Body

```
class GuideService @Inject constructor(
    private val apiclient: DataGuideClient,
    private val daotoken: TokenDao
) {
    @SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation")
    suspend fun getGuide(guide: String): Response<GuideRegisterModel> {
        val query = QueryGuideDto(listOf(query(guide)))
        val bearer = daotoken.getToken().token
        val gson = Gson()
        val json: String = gson.toJson(query)
        val obje: QueryGuideDto = gson.fromJson(json, QueryGuideDto::class.java)
        Log.i("Json", "${gson.toJson(query)}")
        Log.i("Json objeto", "$obje")
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
         //Envia el token y el dataclass QueryGuideDto en formato Json como un String
            //val response = apiclient.getDataguide("Bearer $bearer","$json")

            //Envia el token y el dataclass QueryGuideDto
            val response = apiclient.getDataguide("Bearer $bearer", query)
            response
        }
    }
}
```

my interface

```
interface DataGuideClient {
    @POST("/fmi/data/v2/databases/PLIIN/layouts/GuiasAPI/_find")
    
    suspend fun getDataguide(
        @Header("Authorization") bearer:String,
        @Body query: QueryGuideDto,
    ): Response<GuideRegisterModel>
}
```

my data class QueryGuideDto

```
data class QueryGuideDto(
    @SerializedName("query")
     val query : List<query>
)
```

my data casss quey

```
data class query(
    @SerializedName( "IdGuia")
    val IdGuia: String?,
)
```

my retrofit method

```
fun provideRetrofit(
    ): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BaseURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient()!!)
            .build()
    }

@Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDataClient(retrofit: Retrofit): DataGuideClient {
        return retrofit.create(DataGuideClient::class.java)
    }
```

It only fails me sending the json through the body in the post method

Comment: What do you mean by 'I alter the structure of the JSon by adding slash "/"'? Are you really adding a `/` in some way to the JSON data (in that case please edit your question to include that code), or do you mean you add a `/` to the URL?